# Should pure Joomla questions be moved to the Joomla SO -beta

Tags: discussion

What is the typical procedure when a new specific SO site is created (in this case joomla.stackexchange.com, currently in beta ) Should pure Joomla-questions now be moved to the new site? Or will this be annouced at some point? The Joomla tag description states that new questions regarding the Joomla CMS should be asked on the new site, but plenty of questions are still ending up on SO, tagged only with Joomla-specific tags.

Comment: The questions could still be on-topic on Stack Overflow, so I wouldn't say that all questions would be moved to Joomla.  If you see something that would be on-topic for the Joomla site, then you can flag for a moderator to migrate it. However, since it is still in beta there is no guarantee it will be moved.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is on topic on the site that it is on, it should not be closed or migrated.

Migration is only something to consider when a post is explicitly off topic where it currently sits.  Some sites have a bit of an overlap in scope.  That's okay.

Of course, if a potential site's scope is entirely encompassed by another existing site, then it's generally a sign that such a site need not be created in the first place.  Sites are created to find a place for questions that don't already have a place.  (As a corollary to this, if you think one site's scope is encompassed by another site, it *usually* means you don't understand the scope of both sits.)